# Maya Local Direction

Tags: python, expression, nodes, maya

What I'm trying to achieve is basically local translation in Maya attached to wheels for example:
Moving a car forward in it's LOCAL Z direction and the wheel would spin the same speed no matter what rotation is applied, I've got close, this is what I've done!

1. Connected the parentInverseMatrix and the worldInverseMatrix of the driver into a multMatrix node.
2. Connected the output of the multMatrix node into a decompose matrix node.
3. Connected the outputTranslateZ from the decompose Matrix node into the driven objects rotationY.
   This does work! Only problem is for some reason when I rotate the driver it rotates the driven, that doesn't make much sense to me though, do you know whats happening here or how I may fix it?

Matrix: https://www.dropbox.com/s/udkevskv41ruz01/matrixTest.mb

Expression: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7xikbw4csx8uz4/wheel.ma

Comment: Not at my main terminal, so will pick through the .mb/.ma later, but just wondering, would using a driven key and curves be an appropriate alt approach? e.g. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gaaxz5f6eeo6s45/driven_keys.ma

Comment: Just as a quick one - try recreate your test, but don't freeze the transforms on the driver - that's what's causing your rotate oddness. If you connect up a decomposeMatrix to the matrix plug of your driver cube and then rotate the cube you'll see the TX and TZ channels updating..

Comment: Hey thanks for writing back! I do  have to free the transforms on the driver though? I need to have zero translation transforms so that the animator or myself doesn't have mixed values by default

Comment: Freezing transforms can be a Bad Idea, if nothing else, because you're potentially making what you see in the channel box different to what Maya's _actually_ storing. If you want the driver cube to appear to be offset from the origin but have zero transforms, perhaps group the cube and use the group to apply your offset?

Comment: Ahhh so simple, I'll have a look tonight and see if not freezing them will fix my rotate problem, thanks again! That's what you meant right? If I don't freeze the driver the rotates will not be effected on the driven once translated?

Comment: Essentially yep. By freezing transforms I believe you're baking into the vertices their new position, and throwing out the transform matrix. That's not so bad, but at the same time, then you're doing a rotation with a pivot that's not centered on the origin and thus doing a lot more than you expect. Comments aren't a good way to explain unfortunately (it needs a bit more handwaving and some diagrams) but if you can play around with it locally it might make more sense? If not, let me know, and i'll do up a short piece.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22732/discussion-between-tanantish-and-shannon-hochkins)